# display last 3 months sundays in perl and ksh script

Tags: perl, ksh

I want to display last 3 months sundays in perl script

For example, say today is sunday 2013-01-20, last 3 months sunday from now

```
  2013-01-20
  .
  .
  2013-01-06
  .
  .
  2012-12-30

  2012-12-02
  .
  .
  2012-11-25
  .
  .
  2012-11-04
```

It should change the last 3 months sundays based on current date and time

need the same thing in ksh script for linux

Thanks in advance.

---

Here is the code ..It is giving last sunday..But i need last 3 months sunday

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$today = date(time);
$weekend = date2(time);

sub date {
     my($time) = @_;     

     @when = localtime($time);
     $dow=$when[6];
     $when[5]+=1900;
     $when[4]++;
     $date = $when[5] . "-" . $when[4] . "-" . $when[3];

     return $date;
}


sub date2 {
     my($time) = @_;     # incoming parameters

     $offset = 0;
     $offset = 60*60*24*$dow;
     @when = localtime($time - $offset);
     $when[5]+=1900;
     $when[4]++;
     $date = $when[5] . "-" . $when[4] . "-" . $when[3];

     return $date;
}


print "$weekend \n";
```

Thanks !!

Comment: We will happily help you out with your programming once you have tried your best and become completely stuck, but Stack Overflow isn't a site that provides programming effort for free. If you show your code and explain the problem then we will gladly help.

Comment: You seem to have done the hard part. Just keep subtracting seven days in seconds from the time and you will get as many previous Sundays as you like.

Comment: What do you mean by * the last 3 months sundays*? Do you just mean the last twelve Sundays, or all the Sundays since the same day in the third preceding month, or all the Sundays since the beginning of the third preceding month, or all the Sundays since ninety days ago, or something else?

Comment: @Borodin: from the example, the third

Answer (score 0):

In ksh (tested with pdksh and GNU coreutils date):

```
timestamp=`date +%s`
date=`date --date=@$timestamp +%F`
month=`date --date=@$timestamp +%Y-%m`
for months in 1 2 3; do
    while [[ $month == `date --date=@$timestamp +%Y-%m` ]]
    do
        if [[ 7 == `date --date=@$timestamp +%u` ]]; then echo $date; fi
        let timestamp-=12*60*60
        date=`date --date=@$timestamp +%F`
    done
    month=`date --date=@$timestamp +%Y-%m`
done | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using Perl's DateTime module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DateTime;

# Get the current date and time
my $now = DateTime->now;

# Work out the previous Sunday
while ($now->day_of_week != 7) {
  $now->subtract(days => 1);
}

# Go back 13 weeks from the previous Sunday
my $then = $now->clone;
$then->subtract(weeks => 13);

# Decrement $now by a week at a time until
# you reach $then
while ($now >= $then) {
  say $now->ymd;
  $now->subtract(weeks => 1);
}
```